# What is the minimum version or build version of office 2019 i need to get to test shared javascript runtime?

Tags: office-js

This is a basic question, but I did not find a clear solution.

I saw this link [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) and what i understand is that shared javascript runtime works on all excel versions on windows that are not one-time purchase versions. If this is correct then will it work only with office 2019 subscriptions or office 2016 subscriptions?

If I need to get office 2019 to test shared JavaScript runtime then what office version I should get and what should I suggest to my clients?

Thanks in Advance,
Naveen Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I did some more reading and what I see is that shared JavaScript runtime is supported only in 'Office on Windows (connected to a Microsoft 365 subscription)'. It does not support in Office 2019 or 2016 currently.